# uploading an image as (Byte array) from android to asp.net mvc server

Tags: android, asp.net, model-view-controller, asynchttpclient

im using asynchttpclient in android to upload an image as (Byte array) to the server

```
byte[] bytes;  //incommming bytes


RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("imgBytes",new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

        ServerConnection.get("saveImage", params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "uploadByteArrayPhoto: onFailure: uploading failed "+responseString +" throwable :  "+throwable.getMessage() );
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {

                Log.d(TAG, "uploadByteArrayPhoto: onSuccess: uploading success "+responseString);
            }
        });
```

So my question is how do i handle this in the server side  **(asp.net MVC C#)**,

I need a function in the **MVC** controller to handel this **ByteArrayInputStream** and coverting it to an image file (PNG/JPEJ) then save it in the server ,
So ,i can store the image url in the SQL